# How to combine a Gmail search on senders using two different email ids

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

I have some email contacts who use two (or three) different email addresses.  Sometimes contacts also change emails over time.

This confuses things when I want to search for emails from them in my Gmail online interface.

Right now I use a search string like so:

```
from: foo@bar.com OR foo_other@bar_other.com
```

Is there any easier way of doing this by setting maybe something like an alias? It's also hard to keep remembering who are these people who use multiple emails and what those emails are.

How does one tell Gmail succinctly that search on multiple addresses when I mention a certain person?

Any other tricks or hacks that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Devils in the details.  Based on your addresses I would search more generally:

```
from:(foo)
```

will return both

```
foo@bar.com AND foo_other@bar_other.com
```

You could also create a filter to label mail with 'foo' if it matches

```
from:({foo@bar.com foo_other@bar_other.com foo foo_other bar.com  bar_other.com etc.)}
```

then clicking on 'foo' will show you all their messages.